# jQuery Bootstrap Alternate table row div and add push pull class based on number

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to add a class to columns in a row based on the class the column is using from bootstraps grid. I sort of having working but have to specify the column push and pull classes manually in jQuery.

My HTML bootstrap columns look like this.

```
<div class="alt-col-grid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" /></a> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <h3><a href="#">Feature Column</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ullamcorper convallis consectetur. Nunc pharetra ligula quis mauris aliquam convallis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" /></a> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <h3><a href="#">Feature Column</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ullamcorper convallis consectetur. Nunc pharetra ligula quis mauris aliquam convallis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" /></a> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <h3><a href="#">Feature Column</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ullamcorper convallis consectetur. Nunc pharetra ligula quis mauris aliquam convallis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery looks like this

```
$(function() {
  $('.alt-col-grid div.row:odd .col-sm-4').addClass('col-sm-push-8');
  $('.alt-col-grid div.row:odd .col-sm-8').addClass('col-sm-pull-4');
});
```

It works but how can i make it so if i do not know column class number col-sm-4 and look for the col-sm- and then add the push and pull based on the number. So this column would be 4 so it would add classes for the col-sm-pull-4 and the remaining of the 12 in the columns to the other column and add col-sm-push-8. It would calculate the numbers to add to the push pull classes based on the class of the column divs class.

http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/rxpx1yts/11/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand you. what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly this could help you.
loop through odd rows and get the class names like this :

```
$('.alt-col-grid div.row:odd').each(function() {
});
```

And another loop for columns.

```
$('.alt-col-grid div.row:odd').each(function() {
   row = $(this);
   row.children().each(function() {
   });
});
```

You can get the number by getting the class attr and removing letters.

```
clmnsize = parseInt($(this).attr('Class').replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''), 10);
```

this will give you 4 8 8 4.

Then, since bootstrap has 12 columns you can subtract that number from 12 to find out what's left.
Now this is the part that I'm not sure if its gonna help you or not. basically if you are using only 2 columns and the first one is turning to push and the second one to pull.(It's not gonna work if you have a different scenario)

```
clmn = $(this);
var clmnsize = parseInt($(this).attr('Class').replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''), 10);
newclasssize = 12 - clmnsize;
var extraclassdecider = index % 2 == 0 ? 'push' : 'pull';
var newclass = 'col-sm-' + extraclassdecider + '-' + newclasssize;
clmn.addClass(newclass);
```

So basically, after getting the new number we check to see if its the odd column or the even one and based on that we add push and pull. On the next line we generate the class and finalyl we are adding it to the element.

Here's the full [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxpx1yts/15/).

Comment: PURE genius!!! This works and i can change it to any column number and works!!! AWESOME!!! You Rock!!!

Comment: One thing i did notice is that if you have a nested row with columns in one of the main columns it breaks it. Any way to not add the class to child rows or nested rows and columns in a column? http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/zupy3r7b/3/

Comment: Actually here is a better example of issue. It counts them in the rows when figuring out the odd rows. http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/zupy3r7b/4/

Comment: wait I think by modifying the first line to $('.alt-col-grid > div.row:odd').each(function() { and using the > it fixes it. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes that will fix it. What you have to keep in mind is that, you have to keep the scenario the same because this wont work with changes, i will be glad to help you solve further issues :)